# Implement AOP with groovy to performance profile a Grails app (dynamic weaving, as in AspectJ)

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, aop, expando

I need to collect performance metrics for a bunch of Grails on Groovy apps. I'm thinking of doing it on the basis of a few examples on the web (cf. http://www.infoq.com/articles/aop-with-groovy).
I think I've got what I need to do in terms of collecting perf data across method and closure boundaries.

What I have not a good idea of doing is 
o how can I bunch up my perf stats together so that their granularity is preserved
o how to be able to weave the advice at load time using Groovy/Grails instead of instrumenting the code before run-time

Any (and every) help is very welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Does it really need AOP? VisualVM (https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) worked fine to me. You can fine-tune it to what classes to profile and what not.

Answer (score 0):

first of all: don't do this yourself. especially in Groovy it's not easy to get monitoring done right due to byte code manipulation/optimization by groovyc, possible mess up with AST transformations etc.

take a look at [Spring Insight](http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/6.0/devedition/cinintro.html). It comes with the developer edition of tc-server and lets you monitor everything down to GORM-generated SQL statements.

another thing I'v googled is the [perf4j Grails plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/perf4j), from the documentation it looks pretty what you might need.

Comment: Thanks very much for both of your suggestions - I think  I'll go ahead and use VisualVM and YourKit (I wasn't able to set Insight up correctly - it kept complaining about timeouts upon execution)

Comment: OTOH, I came across this                     http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/10/19/grails-plumbing-spring-aop-interceptors/                                             (Grails is strongly married to Spring) and thought I would play with it; I'll report progress as and when I make some